# Expected number of iterations while counter is less than a random number

Tags: probability

Imagine you have a die with sides numbered from m to n, where $m \le n$.
Lets say you follow this procedure:
Roll the die and take as many steps as shown on the die.
It seems obvious that the expected number of steps you would take is $\frac{m+n}2$
For a normal die, $m=1$ and $n=6$. Your expected number of steps is $\frac{1+6}2=\frac72=3.5$

Take a more complicated procedure:
Roll the die and if the number shown is greater than the number of steps you've taken, take another step and if its less than or equal, you stop.
Programming equivalent is

> What is the expected number of loops of 'for (int i=0; i< Random(m,n); ++i)'?

I've taken an attempt at coming up with a formula for this. Let me explain my logic while working through a small sample where $m=0$ and $n=2$:
The expected number of steps is the sum of (each of number of possible steps multiplied by their probability).

1. The probability of taking $0$ steps is the probability of rolling a $0$ on your first roll, which is $\frac13$
2. The probability of taking $1$ step is the probability of rolling a $1$ or $2$ on your first roll, which is $\frac23$, and also, as pointed out, also the probability of NOT rolling a $2$ on the next roll, which is $\frac23$. The total for this is $\frac23\cdot\frac23$
3. The probability of taking $2$ steps is the probability of rolling a $1$ or $2$ on your first roll and rolling a $2$ on your second roll. This is $\frac23\cdot\frac13$

Summing them together, you have $0\cdot\frac13+1\cdot\frac23\cdot\frac23+2\cdot\frac23\cdot\frac13=\frac89$

Here is the formula I've come up with working backwards from examples I've tried. Note, this formula now fails due to the change in my step #2 above:
$$\sum_{i=1}^ni\frac{\frac{n!}{(n-i)!}}{(n-m+1)^i}$$

Is this correct? Is there a more clean formula? Does this problem have a name?

Comment: On your step $2.$, why is this right?  Why can't I instead roll a $0$ on my first turn and then roll a $1$ or a $2$?  For that matter, why is your step $1.$ right?  In order to move $0$ steps don't I need to throw $0$ twice?

Comment: Sorry, added a bit of clarification in the question. Once you've rolled a number less than or equal to the number of steps you've taken, you're done.

Comment: I still don't understand your step 2.  Even with this change, I'd say the probability should be multiplied by the probability that you don't get to take that second step.

Comment: Nor do I get your step 3.  If I roll $2$ i take a step, but then no possible roll can be greater than $2$ so I can't move another step.

Comment: Oh, i see your concern with step #2.
With step 3, you're comparing roll value to the number of steps you've taken. Not roll value to previous roll value.

Comment: Agreed on 3.  My step 2. calculation would be $\frac 23 \times \frac 23=\frac 49$.  Note that this makes the three probabilities add to $1$, which would seem to be necessary.

Comment: I think, in the end, your question comes down to this:  I have a die with sides $\{1,\dots, n\}$.  I roll it so long as my values keep increasing (strictly).  How many rolls do I expect to make?  I don't immediately see a clean way to settle that...though I expect there is one.

Comment: No, that is an incorrect interpretation of the problem. As long as you roll a number greater than the number of steps you've taken, you roll again and possibly step again. If you don't step, you're done.

Comment: Right, I keep counting the values on the rolls, not the steps.  I like my problem though...I'll think more on that one.  Do you agree with my Step 2 calculation?  If so, I think you should edit your question.

Comment: If you have a 6 sided die, here's an example. Roll a six, that's greater than 0, I'll take a step. Roll a 3, that's greater than 1, I'll take a step. Roll a 5, that's greater than 2, I'll take a step. Roll a 3, that's equal to 3, I'm done. See my addition to the question that includes a C++ example if that helps.

Comment: Well, I still disagree with your step 2 calculation.  And I repeat...the probabilities that you have written do not add to 1.  So either my understanding is badly off (definitely possible) or your calculation is wrong somewhere.

Comment: I agree with your step 2 calculation, I've edited the question to reflect so.

Comment: Ok, then I think I have the game down.  Are you looking for a simple closed formula?  I somewhat doubt there is one.  The probability of taking exactly $k$ steps is $P(>0)\times P(>1)\times \dots \times P(>k-1) \times P(≤ k)$  That is easily computed in each case, but I'm not sure it simplifies much (N.B. I could certainly be wrong about that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity, let's assume that the faces on your die run from $\{0,\dots, n\}$.  the $m$ doesn't change much...it just means that you automatically get to take $m$ steps before the proper game starts.  Let $P(r)$ be the probability of throwing an $r$ and let $\phi_k$ be the probability that you get to take exactly $k$ steps.

In order to move exactly $0$ steps you need to throw a $0$ initially so $$\phi_0=P(0)=\frac 1{n+1}$$.

In order to move exactly $1$ step you need the first throw to be anything greater than a $0$ and you need the second roll to be $≤ 1$.  Thus $$\phi_1=P(>0)\times P(≤1)=\frac n{n+1} \times \frac 2{n+1}$$

In order to move exactly $k$ steps you need the first throw to be anything greater than a $0$ and you need the second roll to be $>1$ and so on  Thus $$\phi_k=P(>0)\times P(>1)\times \dots \times P(≤k)=\frac n{n+1} \times \frac {n-1}{n+1}\times \dots \times \frac {k+1}{n+1}$$

Combining all this (and trusting that there have been no errors) we see that the expected number of steps is $$E=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac {k(k+1)\,n!}{(n+1)^{k+1}(n-k)!}$$

I don't see any way to simplify this, though that doesn't mean there isn't a way.

Comment: When n=4, the expected number of steps is just over 5 according to this formula. [WolframAlpha query](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28%28k^2*4!%29%2F%28%285%29^k%284-k%29!%29,+k%3D0+to+4)

Comment: @VictorStone  Yes, well that might be because I botched the algebra.  I have edited the formula and removed a couple of gross errors.  I might have left some.  Now with $n=4$ I get $E=1.407$ which feels more likely.

Comment: That logically matches your explanation for k steps, except I don't see where $k^2$ comes from. Also, I simulated 100 million trials, for $n=4$, I got this: $\phi_0\approx0.200045$, $\phi_1\approx0.320012$, $\phi_2\approx0.287939$, $\phi_3\approx0.153625$, $\phi_4\approx0.038379$, and $E\approx1.510$

Comment: I get one factor of $k$ from the probability term and one from the expectation.   Wouldn't surprise me if I am still botching the algebra.  I'm tied up now but will do the $n=4$ case by hand later this evening.

Comment: Just ran it.  The exact value is 1.5104,  my analysis seems correct but obviously the summation is still flawed.  I expect I am making an "off by one" error.  I am prone to those.  I'll revisit...either I'll repair it or I'll take down my "solution".

Comment: Ok, I've made my last revision of the formula.  If I have implemented properly on my machine, it gives the correct answer for small cases)...but I have made so many unforced errors on this that I hesitate to claim anything.

Comment: I've run the math and the simulation for $n=1$ through $n=14$ and they are always within $\frac1{1000}^{th}$ of each other. It logically makes sense and I agree with it. Well done!